# dhcp settings wifi radar linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, dhcp, wpa

I am trying to connect to my wifi network. Using the standard connection manager in linux mint 13 xfce was not a good idea. No wifi networks are shown there. and when I left-click on it, the wireless are is gray.

I found the tool called wifi-radar which shows all available networks around. But connecting to the right network is not possible so far. I seem to have configure a lot of things to get it right. However, I receive a dhcp error and I am trying to refer the dhcp setting right. In wifi-radar, it refers to this path:

```
command: /sbin/dhcpcd
pid file: /etc/dhcpc/dhcpcd-%(interface)s.pid
```

when I lookup this file or directory, it is not there. Where should the DHCP setting refer to?

and for the ssid settings: I have a WPA security set. So I guess I have to add it as the tool does not seem to recognize this automatically (why not? the windows xp zero configuration utility does not seem to be so bad at all).
which settings for my wifi network do I have to set?

```
-wifi options:
mode:
channel:
key:
security:

-wpa:
driver:
```

I am dissapointed that it is so hard to connect to my wifi network using a linux version, aimed at user-friendly-ness

output of `iwconfig`:

```
 wlan1     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:10 dBm   Sensitivity=0/3  
      RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

output of `iwlist scan`:

```
 Cell 04 - Address: CC:5D:4E:91:2F:CC
                ESSID:"DAroontjepower"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11b
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality:89/100  Signal level:-39 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Extra:bcn_int=100
                Extra:atim=0
                IE: Unknown: 000E4441726F6F6E746A65706F776572
                IE: Unknown: 010C82848B960C1218243048606C
                IE: Unknown: 02050000000001
                IE: Unknown: 030101
```

one more thought: I read on another site that when you use ndiswrapper, for some networkadapters this means only no security or WEP-security might work.
How can I found out if this cards also belongs to these cards? Might that also explain that wcid-gtk says the network is WEP encrypted?

Comment: If you want the version that is "aimed at user friendliness" use the one that comes with your OS. Why are you using an external tool? You should be able to all this graphically from your network manager which is part of your desktop. If that shows nothing, that's the issue you should fix. Please post the output of `iwconfig`.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. As far as I can tell though, your card seems to be correctly configured. Can you show us the settings in network-manager? Do you have it set up to use DHCP?

Comment: As I said before, please don't add extra info in the comments, it is impossible to read. [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: yes, thank you. when I posted this, I had not seen your comment. Changed it by now, added all the info to the question.

Comment: Then it's very strange that the standard tool is not finding networks. The standard in xfce is `wicd` right? Are you sure it is using the right network card? Have a look at your network settings/wicd settings.

Comment: wicd is the standard. I also installed wicd-gtk. I shows the networks, but still haven't been able to connect. I made a screenshot which is located here: https://db.tt/H8CJYGz5 where exactly should I look for the settings you are talking about?

Comment: You need to click on the ESSID you want to connect to and make sure it is set to use DHCP. Also make sure that you have a working DHCP server on the network. In most cases, that is configured in the router itself.

Comment: I cannot click any ssid and how can I make sure it is set to use dhcp? What I also find very strange is that wcid-gtk says my network has WEP security though it is WPA/WPA2 PSK. this is my screen from wcid-gtk: https://db.tt/Hd45IgNR